# Slick 3.4.1 + Scala Driver org.h2.Driver does not know how to handle URL jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I am using `Slick 3.4.1` and `Scala 2.12` and this is my code to connect to a `MySql` Database:

[image]

while this is mySql workbecnh

[image]

It seems like the Sql is not running though, seen that when I try `ping 127.0.0.1:3306` the output is `ping: 127.0.0.1:3306: Name or service not known`. I really do not know what is wrong.

Comment: Ignoring your sql running or not question, why do you think that your h2 driver should be able to connect to a mysql db ?

Comment: Why not use MySQL driver?

Comment: My mistake, I am using `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` but no difference.